# Building a Decision Tree based on a sparse, multi-value matrix

Tags: algorithm, decision-tree

Decision tree learning algos have a general advantage over eg NNs / RNNs, that their internal structure are humanly comprehensible, and can be sanity checked; and can improve even human decision making. Algorithms like ID3 are excellent for building toy models from even non-toy level data.

For a recent project of mine, there is a large existing database, which contains the outcome column for all rows; however, there are 2 extra complexities:

- Not all column values are filled for every training set - the matrix is sparse, and
- Values aren't binary -there are 2-5 (up to ~7) values for many columns.

I'd like to automatically train & learn the closest-matching decision tree given the data above, and so I turn to the nice community of stackoverflow:

**What specific algorithm can I use to extract a decision tree, given the constrains above?**

Edit note: insta-accept for: naming algo, giving a short description on how it works, and linking to an OSS implementation (in any language) thereof. Thanks!

Comment: C4.5 or random forest.